# Can I compile XML-RPC.net to a static lib and use with DLL?

Tags: c#, static-linking

I'm coming from C++ world. I have a small project in C#, I didn't found a way and I don't even know if it's possible to take a DLL like the XML-RPC.net and compile it so static lib , and then use it with my project DLL, link it statically .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need to do this (you usually just ship dependencies in the same directory as your entry point assembly) but you can merge it into your application using ILmerge if you really want which is equivalent to static linking in the CLR.

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=17630